# algebraic integers in quadratic field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Can you give me a really complete proof tha in a quadratic fiield $Q[\sqrt{(d)}]$ the algebraic integers are:
$\mathbb Z[\sqrt{(d)}]$ if $d\equiv2,3 \pmod4$
$\mathbb Z[(1+\sqrt{(d)})/2]$ if $d\equiv1 \pmod4$

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Is the Galois theory available?  Or are you seeking for an elementary proof?

Comment: See for example [the answers here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654202/determining-ring-of-integers-for-mathbbq-sqrt17/). This is also many other places on the internet (and in books).

Comment: Dear Bar, One thing to note is that it is important in your statement that you take $d$ to be a square free integer.  Regards,

Comment: Check Number Fields by Daniel A. Marcus. If I remember correctly, there is proof of this in that book.

Comment: There is a very complete proof in Dummit and Foote's text.